# Update database from text file if entry is modified and add any other new entries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry if the title is a bit confusing but I couldn't describe my problem any better.

Now, here's what I'm trying to do:

**First, I have a file filled with data like such:**

- title
- tag
- 1
- 2
- Title
- Description
- Etc

**Next, I upload that file to my site which then proceeds to make an array with said data and then inserts it into my database. But this is not the intended behavior.**
Right now, if I upload the same file again, it will re-insert everything and duplicate all entries.

What I want to do is check if the data in the file has already been added, do nothing. If it's been modified, I want to update the database where changes have been made and not duplicate anything.

Here's my attempt at doing so:

```
$register_ep_data = array(
                        'show' => $name,
                        'season' => $srNum,
                        'ep' => $epNum,
                        'app_name' => $epName,
                        'tag' => $tag,
                        'app_about' => $desc,
                        'app_website' => $imdb,
                        'app_release' => $release,
                        'type' => $type,
                        'app_code' => $Frame 
                    );

$update = array();
array_walk($register_ep_data, 'array_sanitize');

foreach ($register_ep_data as $field => $data) {
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $update[] = '`' . $field .'` = \'' . $data . '\'';
    }
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `shows` ($fields) VALUES ($data) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code or if I'm doing this the right way

Comment: What is the primary key on your table?

Comment: Currently, it's app_id which is not in the array. app_id is also set to auto-increment.

Comment: You need to provide the app_id of the duplicate to be able to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. What you're currently doing is saying "hey, if you get a duplicate row on the keyed value then update. Oh and here, just generate some keys for this data" and then wondering why it's not updating the rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this :

```
$sql = "select count(*) from shows where 'show' = $name AND 
                        'season' = $srNum AND
                        'ep' = $epNum AND
                        'app_name' = $epName AND
                        'tag' = $tag AND
                        'app_about' = $desc AND
                        'app_website' = $imdb AND
                        'app_release' = $release AND
                        'type' = $type AND
                        'app_code' = $Frame ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

if the $result is 0 then updated else do nothing...